# Fixing Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two questions:

1. Is there a cleaner way for me to execute this prepared statement? It seems as though there is a lot going on here.
2. Could you please address the part of the code where it states "How can I sanitize this"? I want to make sure its safe.

Btw this all seems to work just fine. Just wanted to fix it up a bit.

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once './config/config.php';
require_once 'includes/auth_validate.php';
include_once 'includes/header.php';
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

//ONLY SUPER AND ADMINS ARE ALLOWED TO ACCESS THIS PAGE 
if ($_SESSION['admin_type'] !=='admin' && $_SESSION['admin_type']  !=='super') {
    $_SESSION['admin_type'] = "undefined";
    echo 'Permission Denied';
    exit();
}

// How can I sanatize this
$customer_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'customer_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$operation = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'operation',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
($operation == 'edit') ? $edit = true : $edit = false;
 $db = getDbInstance();

$cid = htmlentities ($_GET['customer_id']);
$sql = "SELECT  
        (SELECT treatment_log.bdi FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT      MIN(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AND customers.id = ?) AS first_bdi,   
        
        (SELECT treatment_log.pain FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT      MIN(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AND customers.id = ?) AS first_pain,
        
        (SELECT treatment_log.suicidality FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AND customers.id = ?) AS first_suicidality,  
        
        (SELECT treatment_log.bdi FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AND customers.id = ?) AS last_bdi,         
        
        (SELECT treatment_log.pain FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AND customers.id = ?) AS last_pain,      
        
        (SELECT treatment_log.suicidality FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AND customers.id = ?) AS last_suicidality,    
        
        (SELECT CAST(treatment_log.created_at as DATE) FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk = customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?)AND customers.id = ?) AS last_visit,  
        
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) AS completed_treatments,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ? AND missed_treatment='yes') AS number_of_missed_treatments,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bdi WHERE bdi_fk = ?) AS completed_bdis,
        
        (SELECT customers.f_name FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS f_name,
        (SELECT customers.l_name FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS l_name,
        (SELECT customers.status FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS status,
        (SELECT customers.mrn FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS mrn,
        (SELECT customers.ohip FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS ohip,
        (SELECT customers.sex FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS sex,
        (SELECT customers.address FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS address,
        (SELECT customers.city FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS city,
        (SELECT customers.postal_code FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS country,
        (SELECT customers.phone FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS phone,
        (SELECT customers.about FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS about,
        (SELECT customers.date_of_birth FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS date_of_birth,
        (SELECT customers.protocol FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS protocol,
        (SELECT customers.treatment_location FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS treatment_location,
        (SELECT customers.area FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS area,
        (SELECT customers.dx FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS dx,
        (SELECT customers.room FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS room,
        (SELECT customers.coil FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS coil,
        (SELECT customers.target_threshold FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS target_thresold,
        (SELECT customers.number_of_treatments FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS number_of_treatments,
        (SELECT customers.motor_threshold FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS motor_threshold,
        (SELECT customers.threshold_multiplier FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS threshold_multiplier,
        (SELECT customers.created_at FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS created_at,
        (SELECT customers.updated_at FROM customers WHERE customers.id = ?) AS updated_at;";     

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii", $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid, $cid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);        

?>
```

Comment: Hm, can we start with something simpler?

Comment: How would you like me to change the question?

Comment: `htmlentities()` no idea why you're using that. If you're expecting it to help guard against an possible SQL injection, you'd be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Do you have an suggestions as to how I can make this code more secure?

Comment: Just stick to using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comments mentioned, `htmlentities()` is not relevant for protection against SQL injection. It's used when you want to output some content to HTML, and you want to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.

I wouldn't write all those queries as individual subqueries. It's unlikely that you need to get all that information as the result of a single SQL statement. Trying to cram so much work into a single SQL call doesn't make it significantly more efficient, but it *does* make it much harder for you to write the code.

Keep in mind this wisdom:

> Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?

So here's how I would code this:

It's not necessary at all to sanitize, if you use parameterized queries. But here's a simpler way to do it if you want:

```
$customer_id = (int) $_GET['customer_id'];
```

Yep! Just cast to `(int)`. It's simple to write this code, it's easy to explain in a code review, and it executes quicker than a function call.

Then separate the SQL into several queries, grouping them in a sensible way so you don't need subqueries or column aliases. Simpler queries are easier to code, easier to debug, easier to modify if you need to do so later (or if another developer needs to modify it, they will thank you for writing code that's easier to work on).

A simple way to get the first visit is to sort by created_at and use LIMIT 1.

```
$sql = "SELECT bdi, pain, suicidality FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?  
  ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $customer_id);
$stmt->execute();
$rows1 = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Get the last visit - sort by created_at *descending* and use LIMIT 1.

```
$sql = "SELECT bdi, pain, suicidality, DATE(created_at) AS last_visit 
  FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?
  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $customer_id);
$stmt->execute();
$rows2 = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This is a trick: in MySQL true is 1 and false is 0, so you can `SUM()` the 1's as a way of counting the rows where some expression is true.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS completed_treatments, 
    SUM(missed_treatments='yes') AS number_of_missed_treatments 
  FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $customer_id);
$stmt->execute();
$rows3 = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

The other queries are quite straightforward.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS completed_bdis FROM bdi WHERE bdi_fk = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $customer_id);
$stmt->execute();
$rows4 = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$sql = "SELECT f_name, l_name, status, mrn, ohip, sex, address, city, country, 
    phone, about, date_of_birth, protocol, treatment_location, area, dx, room, 
    coil, target_threshold, number_of_treatments, motor_threshold, 
    threshold_multiplier, created_at, updated_at
  FROM customers WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $customer_id);
$stmt->execute();
$rows5 = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

In all these queries, we only need to bind the `$customer_id` once per query, which makes it way easier to write this code. No need to give yourself eyestrain counting the length of a long "iiii..." string and matching it to the number of parameters.

P.S.: I did not test this code, so if there are some typos, I trust you can work them out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your amazing help!

Answer (score 1):

Start with:

```
SELECT {customer fields},
       {MIN/MAX(treatment log fields)},
       COUNT(*) as completed_treatements
       SUM(missed_treatment='yes') AS number_of_missed_treatments
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN treatment_log ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id
WHERE customer.id=?
```

`bdi` doesn't seem to be related